# Reading an 2D array or list with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have problems using OpenCV in python, as I'm quite unfamiliar with it. I'm trying to use a two-dimensional array with OpenCV to find lines in it. The data I have never has been an image file and I don't want to create an image just to encode it to an array again. Basically I search for an array alternative for `img = cv2.imread(file_path)`. This might be obvious how to do, but I couldn't find anything fitting for my purpose.

Minimalistic example for what I'm planning to do:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

my_list = np.array([[1,0,1],[2,0,1],[2,0,2]])
img = cv2.imread(my_list) # this is what I need to replace
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,70,110,apertureSize = 3)
#and so on
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,150)
```

Long story short: how to use an array with OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. you need to add one more dimension to your list of points using `np.expand_dims`

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

my_list = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]], dtype=np.uint8)
img = np.expand_dims(my_list, axis=0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 70, 110, apertureSize=3)
# and so on
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 150)
```

---

EDIT:

As you have clarified that your input list's values are from the gray colour space.
you can simply change array datatype to `np.uint8` and it will work.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

my_list = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]], dtype=np.uint8)
edges = cv2.Canny(my_list, 70, 110, apertureSize=3)
# and so on
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 150)
```

Comment: As the question demands, reading a 2D array as an image, it could be thought of an image as it is. Like `np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]])` is already an image. You should be able to view it with a total of 9 pixels.

Comment: As the sample code suggest, he changes colour space from BGR to GRAY so I thought the input list is in BGR format. Not 9 pixels, only 3 pixels with 3 channel.

Comment: Yeah actually the comment was meant for the question, I just posted it at a wrong place. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake on my side. I just copied the bits and pieces I got already, but I really meant an already gray image as you stated. But reading in the gray scale array didn't work either, so the answer helped me. But sadly it brings up new problems, which are unrelated though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just visualizing with a slightly larger 2D array and detecting the diagonal line present in the array with the following code:

```
my_list = np.eye(100) #np.array([[0,1,0,1],[0,2,0,1],[0,2,0,2]])
gray = (255*my_list/np.max(my_list)).astype('uint8')
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,70,110,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,50)
lines
# array([[[-1.       ,  2.3561945]],
#        [[ 1.       ,  2.3561945]]], dtype=float32)

# original image
plt.imshow(gray, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# canny edges detected
plt.imshow(edges)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# lines detected with Hough transform
im = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

if lines is not None:
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        rho = lines[i][0][0]
        theta = lines[i][0][3]
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
        pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
        print(pt1, pt2)
        cv2.line(im, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]